# An element node 'soap:Header' of the type Element was expected, but node 's:Body' of type Element was found

Tags: exchangewebservices

I get this with EWS when I try to create or delete an item in a public folder while impersonating a user.
It happens only with 2010 users in a different AD site (different DAG) than where the Public folders live.
Users in the same DAG have no issue.

there have been some servers migrated to 2016 but the users are not on those. Don't think it's related.

Comment: I would suggest you enable tracing as a first step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications and see what the actual request/responses look like.

Comment: looks like the managed api shows an error that is not relevant. to the response.
this is in the trace


        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user.</faultstring>
        

Any idea how impersonation can fail for some users? There are no scopes active.

Comment: A pull-subscribing to events of the user is no problem, while that is also impersonated. Reading item properties in their mailbox is fine too. Only when an item needs to be saved to a public folder the error occurs.

Comment: further inspection of the trace shows that the error occurs the moment we try to do a query of the public folder. We don't even try to delete or write, we simply try to retreive an item.

Comment: 2/10/2021 10:38:41 AM : EwsRequestHttpHeaders --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2021-02-10 15:38:41Z">
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-AnchorMailbox: UserXXX@XXXXXXXX.com
X-PreferServerAffinity: true


</Trace>

2/10/2021 10:38:41 AM : EwsRequest --- <Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2021-02-10 15:38:41Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">

Comment: <Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time=....Z">
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
request-id: b9.....c6
X-CalculatedBETarget: mbx-01.XXX.net
Persistent-Auth: true
X-FEServer: XX-YYY-02
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 15:38:42 GMT
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=UserXX@XXX.com=PzdLOz6....; expires=Wed, 10-Feb-2021 15:48:42 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
</Trace>

Comment: The request is routed by an exchange 2016 server to the 2010 server that has the public folders. Is that the problem? As exchange 2016 users can not access public folder. This is a 2010 user but could the 2016 routing mess things up?

Comment: I would say that is the problem eg https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1e9289d8-ba65-4fe8-9708-4c88a1cc58fa/exchange-2016-mailbox-cannot-access-exchange-2010-public-folder-after-mailbox-move-but-new-profile?forum=Exch2016GD

Comment: Is there any way to force routing over another 2010 machine?